# LinkedIn Access Token which I create in Android does not work on web. How can I make one that works on web?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

We have a website which you can sign in with email, facebook and linkedin. The email and facebook logins are working, however there is a problem with linkedin login.

I implemented the linkedin SDK on my app, it works and gets an access token. The problem is, access tokens are defined to devices and I can't use it on my web services.

So how can I get an access token from my android device that works on web?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation on the LinkedIn developer website (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth#mobiletokens), mobile and web-based tokens are not interchangeable.